# I'm switching from JSP to Thymeleaf, what's wrong?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

JSP

```
<c:when test=${image != null && image.documents.size() > 0}">
       <table border="1">
            <c:forEach var="item" items="${image.documents}" varStatus="status">
                   <c:if test="${status.index % 6 == 0}">
                          <tr>
                   </c:if>
         
                   <td>
                            <a href="${item.docUrl}">
                                   <img src="${mite.thumbnail_url}" />
                            </a>
                    </td>

                   <c:if test=${status.index + 1 % 6 == 0}">
                         </tr>
                   </c:if>
             </c:forEach>
        </table>
</c:when>
```

Thymeleaf

```
<table border="1">
        <thead th:each="item, status : ${image}" th:if="${image != null && image.documents.size() > 0}"
               th:object="${status}" th:manifest="${status.index % 6 == 0 && status.index + 1 % 6 == 0}">
            <tr>
                <a th:href="@{item.docUrl}">
                    <img th:src="@{item.thumbnail_url}">
                </a>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
<table th:unless="${image != null && image.documents.size() > 0}">
</table>
```

I'm switching from JSP to Tymeleaf, and if I press search, the table should come out, but I think the Tymeleaf grammar is wrong. But I don't know where I got it wrong.

=================================================

I'm fixing it, but it doesn't work here again.

```
    <div th:if="${image != null && image.documents.size() > 0}">
        <table border="1">
            <tr th:each="item, status : ${image}" th:if="${status.index % 6 == 0 and status.index + 1 % 6 == 0}">
                <td>
                    <a th:href="${item.docUrl}">
                        <img th:src="${item.thumbnail_url}">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div th:unless="${image != null && image.documents.size() > 0}">
        <h3>Not Result</h3>
    </div>
```

When I see the HTML tag, the table should appear, but it is displayed like this

```
    <div>
        <table border="1">
            
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: For starters your HTML is wrong. Your `th:each` should be on the `<tr>` element and you should have an `<td>` inside of your `<tr>`.

Comment: JSP to Thymeleaf? Well, good luck. I am aware that JSP can sometimes be problematic because it is integrated too deeply into web servers. But Thymeleaf is by far the most limited template engine I've ever come across. And I've seen many engines...

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks! i am fixing

Comment: @Codo In Spring Boot, Thymeleaf is recommended, so I am trying to use Thymeleaf instead of JSP.

Comment: I have done a few projects with Thymeleaf and I have not felt any limitations for what I needed to do.